# How to frame Paragraph into multiple lines of 60 Characters

Tags: java, string

I'm new to Coding area I apologize if this Question might have asked previously.
I'm Trying to Achieve like this . Suppose i have a Paragraph or Line which is more than 64 characters like this `I've been using the Lumia 822 for over a month now and I noticed that the moment I reach over 70 characters`

At 60th Character we have word noticed so it should be pushed to next line.
Expected output.

`I've been using the Lumia 822 for over a month now and I 
noticed that the moment I reach over 70 characters`

Could you please help me out how to achieve this.
I have used String Tokenizer and substr() but didnt worked.

Please give your Valuable Suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: Just place a `\n` (line break) character every 64th character in your original string. However, I'd say what you want to do is a bad idea, but that depends on why you want to do it.

Comment: the `I` is the 45 character so at which count you really want to split you can decide in the bellow code.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution:

```
public String appendNewLine(String text, int max) {
    int count = 0;
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            char c = text.charAt(i);

            if (count >= max && c == ' ') {
                count = 0;
                output.append("\n");
            } else {
                output.append(c);    
            }
            count++;
        } 
    return output.toString();
}
```

Comment: Hey Kevin,  The Output for your Code is :-
I've been using the Lumia 822 for over a month now and I noticed 



If you see the word "noticed" word should not come in First line as the total characters Exceeded 60.
"noticed" word should come in second line and so on.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This code will ensure each line is strictly less than or equal to `splitLen`. Any words coming after will be moved to next line.

You can adjust the line width using `splitLen` argument. I have tried to cover couple of scenarios. If anything missing, kindly point out.

```
public String splitString(String s, int splitLen){

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int splitStart = 0;

    while(splitStart < s.length()){

        int splitEnd = splitStart + splitLen;
        splitEnd = splitEnd > s.length() ? s.length() : splitEnd;   // avoid overflow

        int spaceIndex = s.substring(splitStart, splitEnd)
                    .lastIndexOf(" ");

        // look for lasts space in line, except for last line
        if(spaceIndex != -1 && splitEnd != s.length()){
            splitEnd = splitStart + spaceIndex;
        }
        // else (no space in line), split word in two lines..

        sb.append(s.substring(splitStart, splitEnd))
            .append(System.lineSeparator());

        // if ends with space, skip space in next line
        splitStart = splitEnd + (spaceIndex != -1 ? 1 : 0); 
    }

    return(sb.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Redflar , It's Working Thanks a lot !!.